# Merge join cartesian: I can I find the missing WHERE Join condition?

Tags: oracle

I've forgot a JOIN condition. I should search it. But oracle knows which are the tables that he wants to join in a cartesian product.

Is there any way to show the names of the tables?

Comment: In the query plan, I know no way of displaying the columns names involved in a JOIN step. What about posting the query and using explicit JOIN syntax?

Comment: BTW, you can get a cartesian join in a query plan, even if the end result does not involve a cartesian join. Though every time I've seen that, the stats on the table were bad and the plan was junk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables in the `FROM` list are:

```
( a JOIN b JOIN c JOIN ... JOIN k ) , ( m JOIN n JOIN ... JOIN z)
```

how can Oracle know which join condition is missing?

It could be `ON a.someid = m.someid` or `ON a.someid = n.someid` or ... or `ON k.someid = z.someid` or even a more complex one, like:

```
ON  a.someid = z.someid
AND k.otherid = z.otherid
```

Comment: Right. But he could say me: I'm going to make a cartesian product between this two sets of information: table A joined with table B AND table C.

It would help me a lot

Comment: There's a difference between **[Oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database)** and **[Oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle)**

Comment: Do you mean in tagging my post?

Comment: Sorry, no. I just mean that the db cannot really know when you do really need a cartesian product or you have forgotten a condition. I guess it could do somehow what you ask for. But I don't know any way for that.

Comment: If you do use the JOIN syntax, any missing condition is obvious.